# JavaScriptで生成したパスワード付zipファイルにパスワードがかからない

Tags: javascript, コマンドプロンプト

**環境**
クライアントOS：Windows10 Pro（1809）
ブラウザIE11

#### 質問

HTMLファイルにJavaScriptを埋め込み、ActiveXObjectを活用して以下のコマンドから7zipでパスワードファイル付きzipファイルを作成した後、元ネタのテキストファイルを削除する処理を実行しています。

・ソースイメージ
※ダブルクォーテーションなどはイメージなのでテキトーです。

```
var cmd = "cmd /c C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe a -pPassword compress.zip fileA";
wsh.Exec(cmd);
fso.DeleteFile(fileA, true);
```

この時出来上がったzipファイルにパスワードがかかりません。
ただし、元のテキストファイルを消し忘れていた時は問題なくかかっていました。
元のテキストファイルを削除する処理を実装したとたんにパスワードがかからなくなってしまいました。

原因及び対処法をご教示いただけないでしょうか？
宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: 症状は「パスワードがかからない」なのですか? 「zip ができない」とか「zip に fileA が入ってない」ではなく。

Comment: @int32_t　さん
ご確認ありがとうございます。
どうやらzipにファイルに入っていませんでした。
zipが出来上がる前にファイルが消されているかもしれないと分かり、setTimeoutを使って検証中です。
setTimeoutでもハマっていますが。。

Comment: @int32_t  さん
setTimeoutの詰まりも解決し、無事に仕様通りに動作させることが出来ました。
ご回答いただきましして誠にありがとうございます。
大変勉強になりました。

Comment: @taro 解決した場合にはせっかくなので、コメント欄で終わらせずにぜひ個別の回答として投稿してみてください。(このサイトでは自己回答も歓迎です)

Answer (score 2):

`Exec()` は、実行したコマンドの終了を待たずに次の文を実行するため、`Exec()`の直後に対象ファイルを削除すると上手くzipを作ることができません。

`Exec()` でコマンド終了を待つ方法は[公式のドキュメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/previous-versions/windows/scripting/cc364356(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)に記載があります。また、`Run()` にはコマンド終了を待つフラグがあります。

```js
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("calc");

while (oExec.Status == 0)
{
     WScript.Sleep(100);
}

WScript.Echo(oExec.Status);
```